# Java Melody with Spring cloud apps

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

java Melody is good app instrumentation tool with old `Java EE` apps but doesn't find good support with any spring cloud stack apps. There is some support for spring boot app on [Github](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody)

Any pointers will help how to use with spring cloud apps or spring boot app with `eureka`, `zuul`, `config server`

Comment: Have you looked at spring boot admin and if you can use it instead of Melody? https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.0/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. yes I am exploring spring boot admin too and trying to figure out if I get everything that java melody offers.. I see it has lot of useful info which uses spring boot actuator endpoints.